# Training a model to generating application specific configuration

Tags: chatgpt, llm, gpt, prompt-configuration

I'm thinking of building a model which can generate application specific configuration file.

one example can be a simple dhcp server config in JSON/XML format with user asking "need config file in xml format" with ip address range and other information - assumption application specific format is already fine tuned for LLM

Need advise on the approach

1. If already something exists in opensource which can meet this requirement
2. any specific LLM might be more suitable to this
3. offline approach will be preferred